# rails unit test error: "Test is not a module"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use this command to run a unit test in rails:

```
$ ruby -Itest test/unit/post_test.rb
```

I get an error "Test is not a module (TypeError)" and no tests are run.

Could it be related to the fact that I have a model class named "Test"? If there is no way to make that work, what would be the fastest way to refactor and change the class name?

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that I have a model class named "Test"? - yes. I think so

Comment: I'm new to ruby, I use notepad++. Is there trick to change this model/controller/view to a different name or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: Not sure about Notepad++, try RubyMine, TextMate or NetBeans for quickly changing filenames. If you will do it manually - don't forget to change all class names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're right that it's because you've created a model using a name you shouldn't use (Test in this case).

All you should need to do is:

Create a migration to rename the database table: `(rename_table  :oldname, :newname)`

- Rename the model.
- Edit any associations in other models.
- Rename the controller (if required)
- Modify routes.rb
- Modify any links in views.
- Rename views.
- Rename the model in controllers and views.
- Rename and modify any tests.